# How can I write a bash script that recognises parameters as directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have this bash script for shortening my GitHub pushes:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /Users/matias/Documents/GitHub/$1
git add *
git commit -m "$2"
git push
```

I use it like this:

```
matias$ path/to/script.sh project-name commit-message
```

The problem with it is that I have to write the whole name of the repository, and it has to be inside `/Users/matias/Documents/GitHub/`

What I want is that knows that `$1` is a directory and so when I'm typing, hitting tab will autocomplete the result, like using nano or something similar.

Comment: Have you seen [how-to-create-script-with-auto-complete](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68175/how-to-create-script-with-auto-complete)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bash completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html) with the following script `push` :

```
#!/bin/bash

_push()
{
    IFS=$'\n'

    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    tmp=( $(compgen -W "$(ls -d $REPO_PATH/*/ | awk -F/ '{ print$(NF-1) }')" -- "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}" ))
    COMPREPLY=( "${tmp[@]// /\ }" )
}
complete -o default -F _push ./push_git
```

Your script `push_git` would be like :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "repo is $1"
cd $REPO_PATH/$1
git add *
git commit -m "$2"
git push
```

For testing it :

```
export REPO_PATH=/Users/matias/Documents/GitHub
source push
./push_git #TAB
```

When writing TAB after `./push_git` the bash completion function will be executing. From [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34238/complete-files-from-a-different-directory-in-bash), you can complete will the command `"$(ls -d $REPO_PATH/*/ | awk -F/ '{ print$(NF-1) }')"` which list your target path directory item.

If you want a more finished solution :

- copy your completion file `push` to `/etc/bash_completion.d/push`
- copy your script to `/bin/push_git`
- edit `/etc/bash_completion.d/push` with `complete -o default -F _push push_git`
- edit your `.bash_rc` to include `export REPO_PATH=/Users/matias/Documents/GitHub`

Comment: This *almost* works, but it fails in some corner cases: file names that contain newlines, and file names that could be interpreted as matching patterns.